# Notifications on feed post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have a web site where a user authenticates using Facebook and based on an action of the user in my site I post to a friend's wall.

To post on the friend's wall I use the graph api, posting to "/userid/feed". And the posts show correctly on the friend's wall.

The problem I'm having is that if the post has a link on it (using the "link" argument) it won't be displayed in the notifications section of the friend's Facebook (i.e. the globe icon on top). If I just post some message and a picture to the wall it does show on the notifications, but links won't show.

Is this the expected behavior or is it a bug in the API? 
In any case, how can I do something that assures me that my user's friend gets a notification in their Facebook?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected behavior. There isn't really any way around this. You can send an app request that links to the post, but it will only manifest as an app notification, which does increment certain counters, but not the globe at the top.